# OpenSSL DTLS Server - how to split each handshake message into separate packet

Tags: server, openssl, handshake, dtls

I am writing one DTLS server using OpenSSL. I noticed that my server is combining multiple handshake messages into a single packet. Though it will help with better performance. I want to understand if there is any config in OpenSSL to disable this feature and send each message as separate packet?

Below is the screenshot of how it looks now:

[image]

As you can see:
Server Hello and Certificate are coming as one packet.
Server Key Exchange and Server Hello Done are coming as one packet.

And below is the screenshot of how I want it:

[image]

Comment: And you want a bad performance? Would using other implementations (e.g. Eclipse/tinyDtls) help as well?

Comment: I don't want bad performance. The client talking to my server is using a customized SSL SDK. It is disconnecting when server sends multi-message, however it works when each message goes separately. I understand ideally client should be fixed to handle multi-message, but I was also wondering if there is a way to configure it in openssl. I need to use openssl only.

Comment: Ok, at least I understand now your requirement. Depending on your plans afterward, my 7 years experience with dtls clearly points to use a implementation, which is intended for your use-case. Otherwise you will miss features and will be lost in some pitfalls. So, for which use-case do you want to use it?

Comment: Hi @AchimKraus, this is for a streaming kind of application where there is a continuous data flow. So as I shared the network trace above. The client is abruptly closing the connection after handshake is done with an error code `0x80090331` and error message `bad data received in handshake`. I looked for this error and understood that it can happen due to signature algo mismatch, protocol version mismatch etc. But in my case these looks ok as handshake is proceeding. At the end client throws this error code and closes the connection.

Comment: In the working scenario each message is going separately, so last packet `Encrypted handshake message` is 77 bytes. In non working case last packet is `Change Cipher Spec` + `Encrypted handshake message`, that is 14 + 77 = 91 bytes. This is only difference I see, so looks client is not able to handle multi-message in last packet. Do you know any other reason why error code `0x80090331` can occur?

Comment: I developed a lot of the DTLS stuff in Eclipse/Californium, and a few lines in Eclipse/tinyDtls. I'm unfortunately not too common with openssl, for me it looks anyway as an error code of your client and you didn't mention the used implementation there. If you want to check your "hypothesis" with an alternative implementation, I would propose to use tinydtls.

Comment: Thanks @AchimKraus, let me give it a try.